# a phpnuke website

Tags: php, web

I had a website with phpnuke, which I didn't create. But now I am responsible for it, and it doesn't work. It worked before, but now it is not working.

First it just didn't come. just a blank page.
I found the problem was this line in `mainfile.php`

```
if (!ini_get('register_globals')) {
    @import_request_variables("GPC", "");
}
```

and I just commented that. now the first page in comming, but it gives me this warning on top of page

```
Strict Standards: Resource ID#10 used as offset, casting to integer (10) in /www/sites/sanad-rahbordi.sbu.ac.ir/httpdocs/db/mysql.php on line 212

Strict Standards: Resource ID#10 used as offset, casting to integer (10) in /www/sites/sanad-rahbordi.sbu.ac.ir/httpdocs/db/mysql.php on line 213

Strict Standards: Resource ID#10 used as offset, casting to integer (10) in /www/sites/sanad-rahbordi.sbu.ac.ir/httpdocs/db/mysql.php on line 212

Strict Standards: Resource ID#10 used as offset, casting to integer (10) in /www/sites/sanad-rahbordi.sbu.ac.ir/httpdocs/db/mysql.php on line 213
```

and this is the the funtion which contains 212 and 213 lines in `mysql.php`

```
function sql_fetchrow($query_id = 0)
{
    if(!$query_id)
    {
        $query_id = $this->query_result;
    }
    if($query_id)
    {
        $this->row[$query_id] = @mysql_fetch_array($query_id); // 212
        return $this->row[$query_id]; // 213
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
}
```

I showed 212 and 213 lines by comment.
So what is the problem? I can't figure it out.
I tried replacing `$query_id` with `(int)$query_id` in those two lines, and the errors don't show off now, but site doesn't work. I mean the first page comes but when I click every link, it just comes to the `index.php`. no link works.

Comment: Change `@mysql_fetch_array($query_id);` to `@mysql_fetch_array((int)$query_id);` to explicitly cast it to an integer. Sounds like it is a string, then being cast as an int. Also, using @ is typically a 'bad thing'. Why are you using that? Are you sure you need it? What happens if there is an error?

Comment: i am not using anything, it is a cms and it should do everything automatically. but now i get errors. i think it is because of some upgrades in server (not sure).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you said you wrote lines 212 and 213…

Comment: sorry, edited... i didnt wrote that. i meant i wrote the comment to show lines 212 and 213... :D

Comment: Ah. Well, whatever, whoever wrote this code did so a long time ago!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that your trying to use a **resource id** as a **key** in an array. 
This is not possible so php is casting the resource id to an integer.

If you cast the resource by hand this will work and PHP will not warn you about this. 
The `"@"` hides any errors that occure during "mysql_fetch_array". Since you want to see the error, you should remove it.

```
if($query_id)
{
    $intQueryId = (integer) $query_id;
    $this->row[$intQueryId] = mysql_fetch_array($query_id); // 212
    return $this->row[$intQueryId]; // 213
}
```

The else is missing a "{"

```
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: i tried this, the error is gone but the site is still unusable, like i said in the upper comment.

Answer (score 1):

As a whole, it sounds like you're using software that uses PHP code as it was maybe ten years ago. Someone has upgraded the PHP underneath, so the site no longer works.

I would suggest migrating to a modern software, either to version or product. I don't think there's any use patching something that's broken through and through. You'll just get more trouble for yourself as a maintainer.

According to its [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP-Nuke), there exists versions of it that have had "many security fixes" since then. If you want to keep on using the software, I'd suggest migrating to that direction.

Comment: i was thinking of migrating to something like joomla, but i was searching for something that could migrate my data to a joomla installation. i found something but didnt tried them yet. i will try them.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above didn't worked for me. My solution is:

```
if($query_id) {
     $q_id=$query_id[0];
     $this->row[$q_id] = @mysql_fetch_array($query_id);
     return $this->row[$q_id];
} else {
     return false;
}
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't a fix, it just suppresses the errors from showing.